# Windows codepage number descriptive name

Tags: php

I've got access only to the user's Windows codepage number, e.g. 1252. How can I in PHP get more descriptive name of the number, like "Central European Languages" or something nicer than a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a list of the numbers to their descriptions?

Eg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654

Try this out:

```
<?php

function getCodePageName($id) {
    $codePages = array(
        1250 => 'Central Europe',
        1251 => 'Cyrillic',
        1252 => 'Latin I',
        1253 => 'Greek',
        1254 => 'Turkish',
        1255 => 'Hebrew',
        1256 => 'Arabic',
        1257 => 'Baltic',
        1258 => 'Vietnam',
        874 => 'Thai',
    );

    if (!isset($codePages[$id])) {
        return 'Unknown';
    }   

    return $codePages[$id];
}

echo getCodePageName(1250);
```

https://ideone.com/3BY5qu

You could try and find a bigger list and store it in a separate file / db if you wish. I didn't do much searching.